# How to extract the returned JSON to an excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method which calls a web API that return JSON:-

```
public ActionResult CompletedProcessList(int start = 0, int rows = 50)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {            

                try
                {
                    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
                    var url = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/monitoring/running/process/list");                    url.Query = query.ToString();
                    string json = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    return Content(json, "application/json");
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException)
                {

                    return Content("error", "application/json");
                }   }        }
```

Then using javaScript i am displaying the return JSON on table , the javaScript code is:-

```
function getprocesslist(result) {

    $('#tablelist tbody, #tablelist thead').empty();


    var str = 'Total Number Of Processes:- ' + result.total.toString();
        $('#total').text(str.toString());

        var str1 = '<tr><th>NO.</th><th>' + 'Process Name' + '</th><th>' + 'Process Requestor ID' + '</th><th>' + 'Process State' + ' </th><th>' + 'Process Start Date' + ' </th><th>' + 'Process Due Date' + ' </th></tr>';
        $('#tablelist thead').append(str1);
        $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
            var number = key +1 ;
        var str2 = '<tr><td>' + number  + '</td><td>' + val.name + '</td><td>' + val.requesterId + '</td><td>' + val.state + '</td><td>' + val.startedTime + '</td><td>' + val.due + '</td></tr>';

        $('#tablelist tbody').append(str2);

    });
}
```

The above is working fine but i need to implement a new feature where I need to add the following:-

1. two check boxes inside the  "Process Name" & "Process Due Date" column haed,So the user can select any of the two check boxes
2. a button to extract the returned JSON to an excel sheet where the system should include the "Process Name" or the "Process Due  date" or both in the excel sheet based on the user selection.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. for the first part I don't understand what exactly you are asking - make it more specific and ask another question
2. for the second part: I don't know how to export to an excel sheet directly (as xls is a proprietary format) but you can export the data as a CSV (comma separated value) document, which excel understads. [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=json2csv&rlz=1C1ASUT_roRO487RO488&aq=f&oq=json2csv&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.5913&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) offers some solutions for Json2CSV- choose the one you like. In our case we use a combined Javascript/PHP solution:

The javascript - creates the CSV content as text:

```
function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray, documentToExportTitle) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var cols = array.cols;
    var rows = array.rows;

    //convert the cols 2 csv
    var str = '';
    var line = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

        line += cols[i].label + ',';

        // Here is an example where you would wrap the values in double quotes
        // for (var index in array[i]) {
        //    line += '"' + array[i][index] + '",';
        // }

        line.slice(0, line.Length - 1);                
    }
    str += line + '\r\n';

    //convert the rows 2 csv
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        line = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].c.length; j++) {
            line += rows[i].c[j].v + ',';            
        }

        line.slice(0, line.length - 1);
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

   //Call the php which will force downloading and saving in .csv format (which is excel ready)
    $("#reportContent").append('<form id="exportform" action="addressOfPhp" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" id="exportdata" name="exportdata" /><input type="hidden" id="docTitle" name="docTitle" /></form>');
    $("#exportdata").val(str);
    $("#docTitle").val(documentToExportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_"));
    $("#exportform").submit().remove();    
}
```

the php - forces a Download as CSV file prompt on the user's PC:

```
 <?php

        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$_POST['docTitle'].'.csv');

        print $_POST['exportdata'];

    ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using ActiveX , you must use IE so ...

```
function CreateExcelSheet()
        {
            //var x = myTable.rows
            var x = json.length;
            var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
            xls.visible = true
            xls.Workbooks.Add

            var i = 1;
            var j = 0;

            $.each(json, function(index, item) {
                $.each(item, function(key, value) {
                    xls.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = value;
                    j++;
                });
                i++;
            });

        }
```